# How to import subtitle file in video in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, subtitle, video-player

How can I import subtitle files in a video in Flutter? like **vtt** files or **srt** files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a workaround, I am using [mx_player_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/mx_player_plugin) for now. For ex.

```
await PlayerPlugin.openWithMxPlayer(String url, String subUrl);
```

this takes video url and srt url as a parameter and plays video using MX player.

**Warning: phone must have MX Player installed.**

---

**UPDATE**

Try [subtitle_wrapper_package](https://pub.dev/packages/subtitle_wrapper_package#-example-tab-) this supports vtt subtitles. Please check my complete answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58798430/5734205)

Comment: Thanks, but i know that, I wish we have this feature in video player like Chewie.

Comment: Have you tried [subtitle_wrapper_package](https://pub.dev/packages/subtitle_wrapper_package#-example-tab-) this supports vtt subtitles.Please check my complete answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58798430/5734205)

Comment: I have tested, and it really works!!! if you find my answer helpful please accept and upvote:)

Comment: It's really helpful, I tried to accept and upvote, but this message showing to me :(
 

Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.